# html css javascript, How to run script before webpage load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im using look like a lightbox. but my problem is it waits the whole webpage to fully load before the script run.. how can i make my script to run 1st? and do not wait the wepage to load?

css:

```
#overlay {
    display:none;    
    position:fixed;  
    left:0px;        
    top:0px;         
    width:100%;      
    height:100%;     
    background-image:url(gray.png); 
    z-index:99999;   
}

#popup {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;       
    width:500px; 
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-right:300px; 
    top:15%;   
    height:auto;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:100000;     
border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  
}
```

html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";      
  }
};
</script>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">

blah blah blah
```

Comment: you can only use DOM methods when DOM tree is completly built

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what `window.onload = function() { ... }` does.

If you don't want it to do that, don't tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `window.onpaint`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onpaint = function() {
      // Do stuff
      }
    };
</script>
```

But, be careful, you cannot use DOM elements within the script.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the script to the end of your document, just above `</body>` and remove the `window.onload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
overlay.style.display = "block";
popup.style.display = "block";
// ...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried it but it wont work is my bracket correct?  <script type="text/javascript">
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay"); 
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
    
        document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";      

};
</script>

Comment: @AllenAquino Create a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i already try removing `window.onload`  but it wont work is my bracket correct?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay"); 
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";      
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: I see 2 closing brackets, but only one opening.